# C++; Is this the proper way to ensure proper data member initialization?

Tags: c++

I have a constructor for:

```cpp
class Student{
    string name;
    string last_name;
    unsigned score;
...
```

```cpp
   Student(string, string, int);

// Student.cpp

Student::Student(string name, string last_name, int score) : name(name), last_name(last_name)/
,score( score <= 0 ? 1 : score) {} // notice the 'score' initialization.
```

I wanted to make sure the input of e.g. Student s("name", "last", -1); does not mess the whole thing, since student scores are in interval of [1 , 5] and score being of 'unsigned' data type.
It really doesn't matter what type score is, I could've put it as 'int' or 'int8_t' (for memory saving) to resolve the problem but I wanted to know if there is a better way to do this?

Thanks ppl :)

Comment: Please define "*mess the whole thing*". This code will not ensure that `score` will be in a range from `1` do `5`. It will be at least `1`.

Comment: The "proper way" to do member initialisation is what causes the class to fulfills its requirements, and behave in a manner that code using the class expects.    You haven't explained WHY code constructing a student is permitted to supply a value of `score` equal to `-1`, nor have you explained what behaviour is expected versus what "does not mess the whole thing" means - so  nobody can give useful advice. Also, incidentally, having names of arguments the same as name of members is often considered poor style, since mere mortals often have some difficulty reasoning about what the code does.